# List all users in a project in Google Cloud using Python API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-python-api, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to list all users with their access levels, in a project in Google Cloud.

I am able to do so using Command Prompt command, 
`gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT`

However, while I try doing it using [API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.roles/list), I get `{}` as response body.

Any reason why? Or, is there some other way?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API call you are doing (which is [`projects.roles.list`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.roles/list)) lists all custom roles defined in an organization or project, so it does not do the same as [the command `gcloud projects get-iam-policy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy), which retrieves the IAM policy for a project.

A trick you can use to know the API call behind a `gcloud` command is to use the `--log-http` global flag, which logs all HTTP requests and responses, so that you can check the resource being requested. If you run the `gcloud` command you shared adding that flag, you will see the following:

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT --log-http
==== request start ====
uri: https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT:getIamPolicy?alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
```

The method behind that API call is `resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy`, and you can find its documentation page in [this other link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy). In that same page, you can simply add `MY_PROJECT` as the resource and you will see that the reported output is the same as with `gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT`.

Finally, regarding your mentioning of doing this using Python, you can probably have a look at the [Resource Manager Client Libraries documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/libraries), where you will find information on how to install and use them. Then, you can check the [library reference page](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudresourcemanager/v1/python/latest/), where you will find a detailed explanation (and examples) of each of the available methods. For example, here there is the reference for the [`getIamPolicy()` method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudresourcemanager/v1/python/latest/cloudresourcemanager_v1.projects.html#getIamPolicy) that you need to use.

Comment: @SwatiSneha, did you solve it? Could you please provide a code snippet?